# Adding a close button to a jQuery Accordion script

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-ui-accordion

I am wondering if there is a way to add a close button (or action) to this accordion script I'm working on. I have no jquery knowledge, but am eager to learn it.

Here is my accordion code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".accordion .intro:first").addClass("active");
$(".accordion .more:not(:first)").hide();

$(".accordion .intro").click(function(){

  $(this).next(".more").slideToggle("slow")
  .siblings(".more:visible").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).siblings(".intro").removeClass("active");

});
```

});

I would like to add a class to close, so I can add a button in the content to close or .slideUp

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the jQueryUI accordion widget?  It allows you to specify what events will trigger accordion movement.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for, but if you looking for the accordion to collapse you can call:

```
$("#SearchParameterAccordion").accordion("activate", 0);
```

where 
SearchParameterAccordion is the div id,
0 is the index of which accordion to collapse.

I believe you can also use a selector instead of an index.

If this didn't answer your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

settting:

```
collapsible: true
```

will allow you to collapse an accordion pane easily.

Example:

```
$("#SearchParameterAccordion").accordion({
       header: "h3",
       autoHeight: false,
       collapsible: true
});
```